# Calling python help within a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I've a unique situation where I need to print out the help pages for all functions of a given imported module within a script and output it to a file.

```
import modx

for I in dir(modx):
    print help(modx.i)
```

Printing to stdout for now, will pipe to a file later once I figure out basic problem above.

Comment: I don't know what you say.

Comment: what is your question and why is it tagged subprocess?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this to print functions/classes within the itertools module. You can try with your module and check if it works:

```
#Replace itertools with your module
import itertools

#Replace items with iteritems in case of python 2.x
for name,item in itertools.__dict__.items():
    if callable(item):
        print("Name: ",name)
        print("*~*"*20)
        print(item.__doc__)
        print("*~*"*20,"\n")
```

Comment: What I need to do is print all the help pages associated with my module, and output that to a file. I don't need the functions within the module, just the help pages.

Comment: What does the help page in your module look like ? The code above actually prints out the help for each of the functions in the named module.

Comment: Thanks Sarith for your help! This seems to just print the first title or page of the help, each item has multiple pages of text that needs to be scrolled through: for example

Comment: for example                                                                                                      
class BGPSession(cisco.feature.Feature)
 |  Use this class to configure the BGP feature.
 |
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      BGPSession
 |      cisco.feature.Feature
 |      __builtin__.object
 |      Returns: True on success
 |
 |  cfg_aggregate_address(self, address, **kwargs)
 |      Creates a summary address in a Border Gateway Protocol (BGP) routing
 |      table. To remove the summary address, set the optional 'no' argument to

Comment: Can you paste the module text (or part of it) on Pastebin or something..Its very difficult to make sense of python code without indentations.